# Create a list of Tkinter's Canvas drawings

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

Is there a way to append to a list drawings created on a Tkinter's canvas? I'm trying this code

```
from tkinter import *

l = []

def f(c):
    l.append(c.create_oval(10, 10, 200, 300, width=2, fill="red"))
    print(l)

root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root)
c.pack(fill=BOTH)
b = Button(root, text="BOTON", command=lambda: f(c))
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Every time I press the button, instead of appending a canvas object, the list appends an integer so that `l` looks like this:

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
...
[1, 2, 3, ..., n]
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: The object on the canvas are actually ids represented by the `int`s.

Comment: Is it possible to append them as objects?

Comment: The is no object class/datatype. It's just those `int`s. If you want to move the object you can just use `canvas.moveto(l[i], 50, 50)`. The integer is all that you can get. When calling canvas methods like `.move`, `.delete`, `.moveto`, ... you need to pass that `int` as the first argument.

Comment: Oh. Thanks a lot! I was almost banging my head against the wall!

Comment: Do you want me to write a full answer?

Comment: If you want to. Your comment's clear enough. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating objects on a `tk.Canvas`, `tk.Canvas` returns the object's id (a python `int`). That uniquely references the object. Those ids are never reused and can be used in many `tk.Canvas` functions like:

- `<tk.Canvas>.move(...)`
- `<tk.Canvas>.moveto(...)`
- `<tk.Canvas>.delete(...)`
- `<tk.Canvas>.itemconfig(...)`

When calling any of those functions you should pass in the object id as the first argument.